# Using stars in excel RE lookahead

Tags: regex, excel

I want to take a single TAG (example TAG3) from a string using the regular expression (using MUREFUNC in Excel)

My string is something like

```
";tag1;  tag2;,,  ; tag3;tag4..."
```

where ";" and "," are my separators and the spaces are not trimmed

If i want know if exist the "tag3" i check this RE:

```
(?i)(?<=[;,]\s*)(tag3)(?=[;,])
```

but doesn't work.
If i remove the star (*) it works only if all tags are written using "; " or ", " as separators
can you explain me why my RE does not work?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your use of the regex. Does `tag3` exist in the following string? `";tag1;  tag2;,,  ;tag1 tag3;tag4..."`

Comment: No, in your string "tag3" does not exist.
A tag must be in this form:
 ";tag3;" or ";\stag3;" or ";\s\stag3;" or ";\s\s\stag3;" or ";\s\s\s\stag3;" or ",tag3;" or ",\stag3;" or ",\s\stag3;" or ",\s\s\stag3;" or ",\s\s\s\stag3," or ",tag3," or ",\stag3," ... and so on

Comment: Okay. Now that I think about your question again, why don't you not use something simpler? Like `(?i)[;,]\s*(tag3)(?=\s*[;,])`. You are using a capture group already, so your end result should still be the same, right? [Example where it should match](http://regex101.com/r/yU5bE7) and [where it shouldn't](http://regex101.com/r/nE2yX8)

Comment: ok, but with your idea i must trim the spaces after regex.mid(_string_,_your_RE_). how?
I was looking for something more elegant that I would solve the problem in one step

Comment: Do you know how to get the first capture group? If you do, you won't need to trim anything.

Comment: Thanks!
I've tried for a few hours and only now i've discovered that excel works differently from this site (regex101.com).
For morefunc's functions: `(?i)[;,]\s*(tag3)(?=\s*[;,])` and `(?i)[;,](\s*tag3)(?=\s*[;,])` and `(?i)[;,](?:\s*)(tag3)(?=\s*[;,])` is the same thing!! :(

Comment: Okay, going back again to your question, you mentioned "If i want know if exist the "tag3" i check this RE". But why are you trying to trim? As long as you have a match, you know that the tag exists, and if there's no match, the tag doesn't. There's no trimming required here. Unless you didn't mention something...

Comment: :) OK, you are right.. i'm sorry for my english, it is not my prefered language. I'm trying to show the tag if and only if it exists in the string and i want it without separators and spaces. now  i'm using "regex.mid(cellwithstring, myRE)". I thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Excel regex does not support variable-length lookbehinds. Nor does most all regex flavors. (Which means you cannot have a quantifier`*` in your lookbehind assertion).

Just remove your quantifer `*` like so:

```
(?i)(?<=[;,]\s)(tag3)(?=[;,])
```

and it works.  Or better yet, make the `\s` an OR conditional `|`, like so:

```
(?i)(?<=[;,]|\s)(tag3)(?=[;,])
```

Answer (score 0):

VBscript (Excel) does not support lookbehind at all.

I would suggest:

```
[;,]\s*tag3\s*[;,]
```

So to tell if tag3 is present, you could use the Test method of the Regular Expression object as shown in this code snippet.

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[;,]\s*tag3\s*[;,]"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test(SubjectString)
```

Oops, just noted you are using MoreFunc.

Try:

```
=REGEX.COMP(A1,"[;,]\s*tag3\s*[;,]",FALSE)
```

(edited to add case-insensitive option to function